# Как вернуть raidz1-0 пул в zfs?

Tags: centos, raid, zfs

На сервере с Centos  и zfs есть три пула. После ребута один пул отвалился и в статус показывает вот это:

```
zpool status -x
      pool: tank2
     state: UNAVAIL
    status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing
            or invalid.  There are insufficient replicas for the pool to continue
            functioning.
    action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
            a backup source.
       see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
      scan: none requested
    config:

            NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
            tank2       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
              raidz1-0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
                sdq     ONLINE       0     0     0
                sdr     ONLINE       0     0     0
                sds     ONLINE       0     0     0
                sdt     ONLINE       0     0     0
                sdu     ONLINE       0     0     0
                sdv     ONLINE       0     0     0
                sdw     FAULTED      0     0     0  corrupted data
                sdx     UNAVAIL      0     0     0
```

Я так понимаю, что это проблема физическая с винтами sdw  и sdx, или можно как-то вернуть этот рейд к жизни?

Answer (score 2):

> это проблема физическая с винтами sdw и sdx

sdw — повреждены данные
sdx ­— вообще недоступен (отключен или вышел из строя)

> можно как-то вернуть этот рейд к жизни?

если не удастся «вернуть» отсутствующий sdx, то, судя по приведённому там же вердикту:

```
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source.
```

единственное возможное решение: удалить пул и пересоздать из резервной копии.

доп. информация:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/820-0836/gbcve/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/820-0836/gbcuz/index.html